# Levenstein distance substring

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

Is there a good way to use levenstein distance to match one particular string to any region within a second longer string?

Example:

```
str1='aaaaa'
str2='bbbbbbaabaabbbb'

if str1 in str2 with a distance < 2:
    return True
```

So in the above example part of string 2 is `aabaa` and `distance(str1,str2) < 2` so the statement should return `True`.

The only way I can think to do this is take 5 chars from str2 at a time, compare that with str1 and then repeat this moving through str2. Unfortunately this seems really inefficient and I need to process a large amount of data this way.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

Comment: Levenstein distance for only the 5-lenght substrings of `str2` or all of them (eg. both the shorter, 4 chars and the longer, 6 chars which may be at a Levenstein Distance of 1)?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder That was my thought but I need to process every line of files that are ~10GB and I figure this will be pretty slow.

Comment: SO only the 5-length substrings?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder yeah i might just try it and see how slow it is.

Comment: You know that there has been considerable discussion about sliding or rolling windows in Python, some of them involving strings, I expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to generate all the substrings of appropriate length of `b`, then compare each one.

```
def lev_dist(a,b):
    length_cost = abs(len(a) - len(b))
    diff_cost = sum(1 for (aa, bb) in zip(a,b) if aa != bb)
    return diff_cost + length_cost

def all_substr_of_length(n, s):
    if n > len(s):
        return [s]
    else:
        return [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s)-n+1)]

def lev_substr(a, b):
    """Gives minimum lev distance of all substrings of b and
    the single string a.
    """

    return min(lev_dist(a, bb) for bb in all_substr_of_length(len(a), b))

if lev_substr(str1, str2) < 2:
    # it works!
```

Comment: and just for fun I implemented this in Haskell [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1664166)

Answer (score 5):

You might have a look at the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) that supports fuzzy matching:

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.search("(aaaaa){s<2}", 'bbbbbbaabaabbbb')
<regex.Match object; span=(6, 11), match='aabaa', fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 0)>
```

Since you are looking are strings of equal length, you can also do a a [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) which is likely far faster than a Levenstein distance on the same two strings:

```
str1='aaaaa'
str2='bbbbbbaabaabbbb'
for s in [str2[i:i+len(str1)] for i in range(0,len(str2)-len(str1)+1)]:
    if sum(a!=b for a,b in zip(str1,s))<2:
        print s    # prints 'aabaa'
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is usually to play with the insert (for shorter) or delete (for longer) costs. You may also want to consider using Damerau-Levenshtein instead.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem before, and I have not found a solution without involving at least one `for` loop. I have implemented a solution that returns the number of matches under a given tolerance calling the already implemented Levenshtein distance in [polyleven](https://ceptord.net/), which can speed up the calculation.

```py
def count_matches(seq,frag,sim_thresh=0.9):
    cont=0
    n = len(frag) 
    L = len(seq)
    assert(L>=n)
    for m in range(L-n):
        sim = 1-poly_lev(frag,seq[m:m+n])/n
        if sim >= sim_thresh:
            cont = cont+1
    return cont
```

The function calculates a similarity value (between 0 and 1) between a string fragment and all the same-length substrings of a longer sequence, being the similarity `1-levenshtein(str1,str2)/len(str1)`. This normalizes over the length of the fragment so it can give meaningful results for fragments of arbitrary length.